# maximum word split

Tags: python, algorithm, word-break

Given a string s and a dictionary of valid words d, determine the largest number of valid words the string
can be split up into.

I tried solving this problem with the code below but it is not giving me the answer I am looking for.

```
def word_split_dp(s):
    n = len(s)
    ans = [0]*n
    # base case
    ans[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        ans[i] = float('-inf')
        for j in range(1, i-1):
            ans[i]= max(ans[i], ans[i-j] + wordcheck(s,i,j))
   
    print(ans)
    return ans[n-2]
       
        
       
        
       
        
def wordcheck(s,i,j):
    
    for word in dict:
        start = i-j+1
        if(s[start:i] == word):
            return 1
        else:
            return float('-inf')
        

print(word_split_dp(s))
```

Comment: This sounds like variation on this problem: https://thenoisychannel.com/2011/08/08/retiring-a-great-interview-problem/comment-page-1/

Comment: Also, there's discussion of time complexity of this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273505/memoization-algorithm-time-complexity Tech interviewers... What a bunch of ball busters!

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your attempt. Starting from the top:

- Assuming that `ans[i]` represents the maximum number of partitions of the substring `s[0:i]` into valid words, you'll need to make this list one entry longer, so that there is an `ans[n]`, which will eventually contain the answer, i.e. the maximum number of partitions in `s[0:n]` which is `s`. So change:

  ```
  ans = [0]*n
  ```

  to

  ```
  ans = [0]*(n+1)
  ```
- Because of the reasoning given in the first bullet point, the final `return` should be `return ans[n]` instead of `return ans[n-2]`.
- Again because of the reasoning given in the first billet point, the outer loop should make one more iteration, so change:

  ```
  for i in range(1, len(s)):
  ```

  to

  ```
  for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
  ```
- Assuming that `j` represents the size of the substring to test, the inner loop should allow `i-j` to eventually reach back to 0, so `j` should be able to reach the value `i`. That means the inner loop should make *two* more iterations. So change:

  ```
  for j in range(1, i-1):
  ```

  to

  ```
  for j in range(1, i+1):
  ```
- In `wordcheck`, the slice from `s` should start at `i-j`, as `j` represents the size of the slice. So change:

  ```
  start = i-j+1
  ```

  to

  ```
  start = i-j
  ```
- In `wordcheck`, the loop will always exit in its first iteration. It cannot loop more as it always executes a `return`. You should not exit the loop when there is no success. The `return float('-inf')` should only be made when all words have been tried. So remove:

  ```
      else:
          return float('-inf')
  ```

  and instead add at *after* the loop:

  ```
  return float('-inf')
  ```

Those are the issues. The code with all those corrections:

```
def word_split_dp(s):
    n = len(s)
    ans = [0]*(n+1)  #correction
    # base case
    ans[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, len(s) + 1): # correction
        ans[i] = float('-inf')
        for j in range(1, i + 1): # correction
            ans[i] = max(ans[i], ans[i-j] + wordcheck(s,i,j))
   
    print(ans)
    return ans[n] # correction
        
def wordcheck(s,i,j):
    words=("war","month","on","the","heat","eat","he","arm","at")
    for word in words:
        start = i-j # correction
        if s[start:i] == word:
            return 1
        # don't interrupt loop otherwise
    return float('-inf')
        
s="warmontheheat"
print(word_split_dp(s))  # -inf
s="warontheheat"
print(word_split_dp(s))  # 5
```